# consulta de 1 tabla relacionada con 3 mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

tengo 3 tablas:
1. aportes
2. aportes_voluntarios
3. aportes_multas
todas estas tablas tienen un campo importe, y todas estan relacionadas con la tabla:
4. asociados
lo que deseo es mostrar al asociado y la sumatoria de sus importes en una sola consulta(y que en una sola linea me muestre todos los aportes por cada asociado)
adjunto la consulta que hice, pero que no me bota los resultados correctos me bota cifras que no corresponden

```
SELECT A.id_asociados, 
       Concat(A.nombres, ' ', A.a_paterno, ' ', A.a_materno) AS socios, 
       Sum(B.importe)                                        AS 'obligatorio', 
       Sum(C.importe)                                        AS 'voluntario', 
       Sum(M.importe)                                             AS 'multas' 
FROM   asociados A 
       INNER JOIN aportes B 
               ON A.id_asociados = B.id_asociados 
       INNER JOIN aportes_voluntarios C 
               ON A.id_asociados = C.id_asociados 
       INNER JOIN aportes_multas M 
               ON A.id_asociados = M.id_asociados 
GROUP  BY A.id_asociados
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  A.id_asociados,concat(A.nombres,' ',A.A_paterno,' ',A.A_materno) as socio,
    A.dni,B.obligatorio,C.voluntario,D.multas
    FROM asociados A
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_asociados,
                  SUM(importe)  AS 'obligatorio'
                  FROM aportes
                  GROUP BY id_asociados
            ) B
        ON A.id_asociados = B.id_asociados
                  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_asociados,
                               SUM(importe)  AS 'voluntario'
                               FROM aportes_voluntarios
                               GROUP BY id_asociados
                          ) C
                         ON A.id_asociados = C.id_asociados
                             LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_asociados,
                                          SUM(importe)  AS 'multas'
                                          FROM aportes_multas
                                          GROUP BY id_asociados
                                      ) D
                                      ON A.id_asociados = D.id_asociados   
 GROUP BY A.id_asociados,B.obligatorio,C.voluntario,D.multas
```

LO RESOLVI DE ESTA MANERA(por si a alguien el sirve)